# Is it possible to LIMIT query result depending on user input?

Tags: java, jsp

So heres my index page.

```
<form action="worker.jsp">
  <input type="text" name="count"></input>
</form>
```

and heres my worker.jsp.

```
<jsp:useBean id="ff" class="my.dbController" scope="page"/>
String count = (request.getParameter("count"));
ff.queryTest(count)
```

and heres the java dbController file.

```
String query = "Select * from table limit ?"
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, x);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Would this be possible? I've been trying it this way but it keeps returning 0 data.

Edit: **I was able to fix it, i had one error in my .jsp files**. Thanks anyway

Comment: If it's a query, you should use `executeQuery`, not `executeUpdate`

Comment: nevermind I was able to fix it, i had an error in one of my .jsp files. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an `executeUpdate` when you should do an `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

1)You've already prepared the statement so executeUpdate() will not work. 
2)The limit parameter accepts int. No need to pass a string to it.

Do

```
ps.setInt(1,limit);
ps.executeUpdate(query);
```

Always have a proper naming convention instead of naming variables like x,y :)

Comment: *ps.executeQuery(query);